# Selenium error - .firefox.GeckoDriverService.sendOutputTo(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V - java

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to trigger selenium FF driver in my MAC.
But I am getting following error.How to fix this issue.

Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.sendOutputTo(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V
```

code :

```
final String geckoDriverPathMac = "/geckodriver/geckodriver-23";
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",geckoDriverPathMac);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.quit();
```

FF version : 64

Geckodriver version : 23

OS : mac

selenium : 3.14.0

Comment: Did you clean your project?

Comment: I guess my phantomjs dependency is causing this problem with FF configuration.Now i removed my phantomjs  dependency and  code is working fine

Comment: yeah, sometimes less is more.